# Getting an error of 'int' object is not callable when using zip function with list comprehension

Tags: list, zip, list-comprehension, typeerror, callable

I have got a code as follows:

```
def column_sum(lst):
      return [sum(i) for i in zip(*lst)]

lst = [[1, 5, 3], [2, 7, 8], [4, 6, 9]]
print(column_sum(lst))
```

This code is to add column-wise numbers in a nested list. This has been
run without any error.

I am also wanting to print the sum of the numbers column-wise. So,
this is my code-

```
sum=0 N,X=list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(X):
   lst.append([int(x) for x in input().split()[:N]])
print(lst)
print(list(zip(*lst)))
lst2=[sum(i) for i in zip(*lst)]
print(lst2)
```

So, I have written the same statement written in the return statement
of the previous program as- `lst2=[sum(i) for i in zip(*lst)]` and I am
getting an error in this line that TypeError: 'int' object is not
callable.

Kindly explain to me why?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is too complicated for the simplicity of the task you are given. Playing with indices is easier and less time consuming.

```
lst = [[1, 5, 3], [2, 7, 8], [4, 6, 9]]

lc_sum=[]
for i in range(len(lst)):
  tmp=0
  for j in range(len(lst[i])):
    tmp+=lst[i][j]
  lc_sum.append(tmp)
lc_sum #[9, 17, 19]
```

As the length of your rows and columns are fixed it is also relevant to look at the side of numpy:

```
import numpy as np

n_lst = np.asarray(lst)
np.sum(n_lst, axis=1) #[ 9 17 19]
np.sum(n_lst, axis=0) #[ 7 18 20]
```